# Why are only few letters in title of this poem in capital letters while others are not?

Tags: capitalization, writing

The poem is ‘Have you earned your tomorrow’ by Edgar Guest. In my textbook , only certain letters first word is in capital while others are not. My question is why is that ?[image]

Comment: If the nominated duplicate doesn't answer this question, please [edit] to ask a more focused question which needs a different answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for the duplicate question.